# How can I fix Project “MyApp” Is not a gradle based project

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

I’m doing some work on an existing flutter project which I have Imported into Android Studio. I’m receiving the below error when I’m trying sync the project after editing the gradle when connecting the project to Firebase.
I have edited the project and app level gradles as per the firebase instructions but get the below error.

Project “MyApp” Is not a gradle based project.

Just wondering how I can fix this?

Thanks

Comment: Post your project tree

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Your project mightnot complied with gradle.  I suggest you only copy xml code and java class code into Android studio but at first creat a mainActivity into Android studio.Hope it will works.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer. Probably comment it

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).